# Enable SwiftLint only for the new files

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I have a pretty huge iOS(legacy) project in which I want to add SwiftLint. All the rules I wish to enforce, I would enforce only on new created files. In that way I do not have to go back and fix all the problems that would come up because the rules have not been followed in the past (as there was no SwiftLint in use). I am not sure how to achieve this?

Comment: Swiftlint has include/exclude directives to select files. However, it's usually better to fix at least basic problems in the old code. Many problems can be fixed automatically and frankly, it's not that difficult. I have already fixed big projects this way.

Comment: @Sulthan Unfortunately, there is too much warnings and errors to fix. Most of them are not easy to fix as they would require the change of the logic. Using exclude directive is also not helpful as I cannot exclude folders (for example). In the future new files may be added to them. Also, adding every file to the exclusion list is not an option as there is too much of them.

Comment: You have to choose. Either you create a clear distinction between old and new code, e.g. using folders, or start fixing the old code.

Comment: I understand. So there is no easy way to say to SwiftLint: Hey, I added you to the project, please do not look at the old files, only new?

Comment: Maybe create a bash script to loop through files with recent mtime (or git changed files), and then inside that loop do `swiftlint lint --path "$filename"` .

Answer (score 0):

you can run a script like this

```
    # Run SwiftLint
    START_DATE=$(date +"%s")
    
    SWIFT_LINT=/usr/local/bin/swiftlint
    
    # Run SwiftLint for given filename
    run_swiftlint() {
        local filename="${1}"
        if [[ "${filename##*.}" == "swift" ]]; then
            #${SWIFT_LINT} autocorrect --path "${filename}"
            ${SWIFT_LINT} lint --path "${filename}"
        fi
    }

    if [[ -e "${SWIFT_LINT}" ]]; then
        echo "SwiftLint version: $(${SWIFT_LINT} version)"
        # Run for both staged and unstaged files
        git diff --name-only | while read filename; do run_swiftlint                 "${filename}"; done
        git diff --cached --name-only | while read filename; do                 run_swiftlint "${filename}"; done
    else
        echo "${SWIFT_LINT} is not installed."
        exit 0
    fi

    END_DATE=$(date +"%s")

    DIFF=$(($END_DATE - $START_DATE))
    echo "SwiftLint took $(($DIFF / 60)) minutes and $(($DIFF % 60)) seconds to complete."
```

Simply add a build phase run script to Xcode with the following

```
"${SRCROOT}/Scripts/swiftlint.sh"
```

It comes from here https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/413#issuecomment-184077062

It doesn't work on the M1 chip because you need to say something like this

```
if test -d "/opt/homebrew/bin/"; then
  PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin/:${PATH}"
fi

export PATH

if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fine
```

based on this blog https://www.anotheriosdevblog.com/installing-swiftlint-on-a-m1/

Comment: what it does it will run on only uncommitted files. So if you touch an old file it will run lint on it. Not exactly what the answer is looking for but it did solve the problem for us adding SwiftLint to an old project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using feature branches you can run it as follows:

```sh
swiftlint --config PATH/TO/CONFIG/.swiftlint.yml $(git diff develop --name-only | grep .swift)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do had a legacy code base and I tried the solution from [here](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/413#issuecomment-999639676)
but I ran into problems

1. Many of my folders had spaces and the script broke.
2. Even after fixing the spaces I was getting "no lintable files found at paths", then had to add relative paths `$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/${filename}`

Here is the full updated script, but let me know if there is any better fix

```
    # Variables
START_DATE=$(date +"%s")
SWIFT_LINT="/usr/local/bin/swiftlint"
hasErrors=0

# Run SwiftLint for given filename
run_swiftlint() {
    local filename="${1}"
    if [[ "${filename##*.}" == "swift" ]]; then
        "${SWIFT_LINT}" lint "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/${filename}"
        if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
            hasErrors=1
        fi
    fi
}

if [[ -e "${SWIFT_LINT}" ]]; then
    echo "SwiftLint version: $("${SWIFT_LINT}" version)"
    # Run for staged files
    git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only | while IFS= read -r filename; do
        run_swiftlint "${filename}"
    done

    # Run for unstaged files
    git diff --cached --diff-filter=d --name-only | while IFS= read -r filename; do
        run_swiftlint "${filename}"
    done
    
    # Run for added files
    git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | while IFS= read -r filename; do
        run_swiftlint "${filename}"
    done
else
    echo "${SWIFT_LINT} is not installed."
    exit 0
fi

END_DATE=$(date +"%s")
DIFF=$(($END_DATE - $START_DATE))
echo "SwiftLint took $(($DIFF / 60)) minutes and $(($DIFF % 60)) seconds to complete."
exit $hasErrors
```